# Scrapy error - NotSupported: Response content isn't text

Tags: python, scrapy

When I crawl data from detail page of this [page](http://edirectory.matrade.gov.my/application/edirectory.nsf/category?OpenForm&query=product&code=PT&sid=BED1E22D5BE3F9B5394D6AF0E742828F), I have error **scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported**:  I can still get data with a small number of pages but when I increase the amount of pages, scrapy run but without output more, it runs and cannot stop.

The pages have images but I don't want to crawl images, maybe have **Response content isn't text**.

This is the error:

```
2017-02-18 15:35:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.google.com.my:443/maps/place/bs+bio+science+sdn+bhd/@4.109495,109.101269,2856256m/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xb11eb29219c723f4?source=s_q&hl=en> from <GET http://maps.google.com.my/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&q=bs+bio+science+sdn+bhd&vps=1&jsv=171b&sll=4.109495,109.101269&sspn=25.686885,46.318359&ie=UTF8&ei=jPeISu6RGI7kugOboeXiDg&cd=1&usq=bs+bio+science+sdn+bhd&geocode=FQdNLwAdEm4QBg&cid=12762834734582014964&li=lmd>
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://com> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: address 'com' not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.byunature> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: address 'www.byunature' not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.borneococonutoil.com> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: address 'www.borneococonutoil.com' not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://com>: DNS lookup failed: address 'com' not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.byunature>: DNS lookup failed: address 'www.byunature' not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.borneococonutoil.com>: DNS lookup failed: address 'www.borneococonutoil.com' not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
2017-02-18 15:35:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.google.com.my/maps/place/bs+bio+science+sdn+bhd/@4.109495,109.101269,2856256m/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xb11eb29219c723f4?source=s_q&hl=en&dg=dbrw&newdg=1> from <GET https://www.google.com.my:443/maps/place/bs+bio+science+sdn+bhd/@4.109495,109.101269,2856256m/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xb11eb29219c723f4?source=s_q&hl=en>
2017-02-18 15:35:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.com.my/maps/place/bs+bio+science+sdn+bhd/@4.109495,109.101269,2856256m/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xb11eb29219c723f4?source=s_q&hl=en&dg=dbrw&newdg=1> (referer: http://www.bsbioscience.com/contactus.html)
2017-02-18 15:35:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.canaanalpha.com/extras/Anistrike_Poster.pdf> (referer: http://www.canaanalpha.com/anistrike.html)
2017-02-18 15:35:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.canaanalpha.com/extras/Anistrike_Poster.pdf> (referer: http://www.canaanalpha.com/anistrike.html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "D:\Scrapy\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\tu2.py", line 17, in parse
    company = response.css('font:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\response\__init__.py", line 97, in css
    raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")
NotSupported: Response content isn't text
2017-02-18 15:35:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-02-18 15:35:41 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (30 items) in: tu2.json
2017-02-18 15:35:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 55,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported': 31,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 24,
```

My code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
# import LxmlLinkExtractor as LinkExtractor

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tu2"

    def start_requests(self):
        baseurl = 'http://edirectory.matrade.gov.my/application/edirectory.nsf/category?OpenForm&query=product&code=PT&sid=BED1E22D5BE3F9B5394D6AF0E742828F'
        urls = []
        for i in range(1,  3):
            urls.append(baseurl + "&page=" + str(i));

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        company = response.css('font:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first()

        key3 = "Business Address";
        key4 = response.css('tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) b::text').extract_first();
        key5 = response.css('tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(1) b::text').extract_first();

        value3 = response.css('tr:nth-child(3) .table-middle:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first();
        value4 = response.css('tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first();
        value5 = response.css('tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first();
       

        # bla = {}
        # if key3 is not None:
        #     bla[key3] = value3;

        if value3 is not None:
            json_data = {
                'company' : company,
                key3: value3,
                key4: value4,
                key5: value5,
              
               

            };
            yield json_data
            # yield json.dumps(bla)

        # detail page
        count = 0;
        for button in response.css('td td a'):
            detail_page_url = button.css('::attr(href)').extract_first();
            if detail_page_url is not None:
                page_urls = response.urljoin(detail_page_url);
                yield scrapy.Request(page_urls, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.canaanalpha.com/extras/Anistrike_Poster.pdf> (referer: http://www.canaanalpha.com/anistrike.html)
```

The spider is crawling a pdf file here. You need to filter those out manually or use `LinkExtractor` which already does that.

```
def parse(self, response):
    url = 'someurl'
    if '.pdf' not in url:
        yield Request(url, self.parse2)
    # or
    le = LinkExtractor()
    urls = le.extract_links(response)
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse2)
```

By default LinkExtractor ignores a lot of non-html files, including pdf - see [source here for full list](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py#L21)

For your code example, try this:

```
# detail page
count = 0;
link_extractor = LinkExtractor(restrict_css='td td a::attr(href)')
urls = link_extractor.extract_links(response)
for detail_page_url in urls:
    url = response.urljoin(detail_page_url);
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: @Granitosarus Thanks but I how to create a filter for it, create filter in __init__.py followed your link? And do you mean we can remove it, no process that pdf link?

Comment: @RoShanShan Yeah, just don't process pdf links. The second example after `#or` is all you need, really. See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#link-extractors

Comment: I really don't know where to put the code after `#or. I want to extract data from detail of this link: [link](http://edirectory.matrade.gov.my/application/edirectory.nsf/category?OpenForm&query=product&code=PT&sid=BED1E22D5BE3F9B5394D6AF0E742828F). You can see my codes above.

Comment: @RoShanShan see my edit for an example how your code could be improved to solve this issue.